# Why does a HashSet in Java need to be iterated?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashset

I understand that in Java, the HashMap class implements the Map interface and the HashSet class implements the Set interface.

I also understand that both those classes are implementations of a hash table.

That said, why is it necessary to iterate through a HashSet while a HashMap has a get() method? Isn't the point of having a hash table being able to fetch an element through a value associated to it?

I've looked up the docs and done some searching and could not find an answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would be the point of a `get()` method on a `Set`? The only meaningful thing it could do is tell you whether the passed object is in the set or not, which is already exactly what `contains()` does.

Comment: It would be a useful operation to be able to retrieve said object from the `Set`. If it contains the reference to the object, wouldn't that be doable?

Comment: but you already have to have a reference to the object to begin with if you want to call `get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also understand that both those classes are implementations of a
>   hash table.

I think you're guilty of assuming too much about the implementation.  As with all objects, the key is the public interface the designer chooses to expose to you.

The `Set` interface does not include a get method to access individual objects directly.  The semantics are different from `Map`, by design.

Comment: You're right about me assuming too much about the implementation. About the `get()` method, you could say I'm "questioning the gods" on this one. Why not include a `get()` method on the HashSet class to access the object directly?

Comment: Set uses bag semantics - you don't get access to a particular element the way you do with Map.  Might have to do with the uniqueness requirement built into Set - no two objects are alike.  What does get mean if you add a duplicate to the Set?  Do you get its twin, or your object?  I think the explanation requires an understanding of all requirements for Set.

Comment: Thank you. You have answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

A `get()` method of `HashSet` (or any `Set` implementation) would be redundant, since if `set.contains(x)` returns `true`, you already have a reference (`x`) to an instance which is deemed equal to the corresponding element of the `Set`.

In the `Map` interface you need `map.get(key)` in order to obtain the value associated with the key. In the `Set` interface, there is only the key, with no (meaningful) value associated to it.

> I also understand that both those classes are implementations of a hash table.

If by that statement you meant that `HashSet` is implemented with a backing `HashMap` instance, that's just an implementation detail. The values corresponding to the keys of this backing `HashMap` are all references to the same dummy object. There's no reason to ever call `get()` for the backing `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no get method because, hashset are internally backed by hashMap and all your values of set are actually stored as keys of this HashMap and values is just a constant field called "PRESENT". So if you have a get() it will cause a problem.

Please refer below link for more details
http://www.java67.com/2014/01/how-hashset-is-implemented-or-works-internally-java.html